# Set number of records to process in Batch process?

Tags: apex, batch

How can I set a limit on the number of records processed in my batch process?
Say the QueryLocator pulls 500 records.  I'd like to break this up so 500 records are processed 10 records at a time.

## CleanUpRecords.cls

```
global class CleanUpRecords implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    
    global final String query;
        
    global CleanUpRecords (String q) {
        query = q;
    }
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
        delete scope;
        Database.emptyRecycleBin(scope);
    }
    
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        AsyncApexJob a = 
            [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed,
            TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email 
            FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = 
            :BC.getJobId()];
            
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can specify the batch size when calling the batch via:

[`Database.executeBatch(Object batchClassObject, Integer scope)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_executeBatch_2).

The `scope` integer is how many records will be passed to your `execute()` method. Some other notes from the documentation:

> The value for scope must be greater than 0.
>
> If the start method of the batch class returns a Database.QueryLocator, the scope parameter of Database.executeBatch can have a maximum value of 2,000. If set to a higher value, Salesforce chunks the records returned by the QueryLocator into smaller batches of up to 200 records. If the start method of the batch class returns an iterable, the scope parameter value has no upper limit; however, if you use a very high number, you could run into other limits.
>
> Apex governor limits are reset for each execution of execute.

Schedule your class either in code, or through the developer console, with this snippet:

```
CleanUpRecords batch = new CleanUpRecords();  
Database.executeBatch(batch, 10);
```

Comment: From the documentation: This parameter specifies the number of records that should be passed into the execute method. Use this parameter when you have many operations for each record being passed in and are running into governor limits.  This value must be greater than zero. If the start method of the batch class returns a QueryLocator, the optional scope parameter of Database.executeBatch can have a maximum value of 2,000. If set to a higher value, Salesforce chunks the records returned by the QueryLocator into smaller batches of up to 2,000 records.

Comment: Documenation: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm

Comment: I'm not quite getting how to place this parameter in my class, even after looking at the documentation.  How would I modify this section of my code?

Comment: global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
        delete scope;
        Database.emptyRecycleBin(scope);
    }

Comment: So what would help me is if I could modify my original code, my original post, so it could set the batch at 10.

Comment: I should say, this is how I've been trying to call the class:
        Test.startTest();
        CleanUpRecords cr = new CleanUpRecords(query);
        Test.stopTest();

Comment: Maybe this way?
        Test.startTest();
        // CleanUpRecords cr = new CleanUpRecords(query);
        CleanUpRecords batch = new CleanUpRecords (query);
        Database.executeBatch(batch, 10);
        Test.stopTest();

Comment: Didn't do it.  My test class gives this error, very frustrating...:FATAL_ERROR System.UnexpectedException: No more than one executeBatch can be called from within a testmethod.  Please make sure the iterable returned from your start method matches the batch size, resulting in one executeBatch invocation.

Comment: For test class, the batch should only be called one, with exactly 200 records.